# Finding price for desired margin

Tags: linear-algebra, finance, economics

My algebra is rusty, I'm trying to rearrange an equation, the purpose of which is to calculate the price that would result in a desired margin. Here are my workings:

```
p = price
c = cost
m = margin
P = profit = p - c
```

$$m = 100\frac{P}{p}$$
$$m = 100\frac{p-c}{p}$$
$$\frac{m}{100} = \frac{p-c}{p}$$
$$p\frac{m}{100} = p-c$$

$$p = \frac{pm}{100} + c$$

I'm stuck at this point. I can't figure out how to factor out p from the RHS. Can someone show me how to continue?

Comment: $p = c/(1-m/100)$

Comment: hint: $\frac{p-c}{p} = 1-\frac{c}{p}$

Comment: @DavidDiaz I tried that and I get to $$p = \frac{100c}{m-100}$$ which doesn't seem right

Comment: Probably since you should have $$ p = \frac{100 c}{100 - m} $$

Comment: @StanTendijck Thank you! I can see where I went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the full workings to convert the margin equation to the price equation, for anyone interested. Thanks to @DavidDiaz and @StanTendijck for pointing me in the right direction.

$$m = 100\frac{p-c}{p}$$
$$m = 100(1 -\frac{c}{p})$$
$$m = 100 - \frac{100c}{p}$$
$$m-100 = -\frac{100c}{p}$$
$$\frac{1}{p} = -(\frac{m-100}{100c})$$
$$\frac{1}{p} = \frac{100-m}{100c}$$
$$p = \frac{100c}{100-m}$$